# Is there any better way of evaluating the summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof

> Evaluate $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{(2r-1)^2(2r+1)^2}$$

**Solution that I have**
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{(2r-1)^2(2r+1)^2}=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r}{16r^4-8r^2+1}$$
$$=\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^n\left(-\frac{1}{32\left(r+\frac12\right)^2}+\frac{1}{32\left(r-\frac12\right)^2}\right)}$$
Now this is a simple telescopic series yielding the answer $$\frac18-\frac{1}{32\left(n+\frac12\right)^2}=$$
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)^2}$$
My question is **how on earth** one will imagine the thing written in coloured letters.

Is there any other nicer way$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Factor the denominator $16 r^4 - 8 r^2+1 = 16(r-1/2)^2(r+1/2)^2$, then partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: $$\frac{r}{(2r-1)^2(2r+1)^2}=\frac{1}{8}\Big(\frac{1}{(2r-1)^2}-\frac{1}{(2r+1)^2}\Big)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).
$$
\frac{r}{(2r-1)^2(2r+1)^2} = \frac{1}{16}\frac{r}{(r-1/2)^2(r+1/2)^2}
$$
where the denominator has two zeros with multiplicity two. The general theory of partial fraction decomposition states that
$$
 \frac{r}{(r-\frac 12)^2(r+\frac 12)^2} = \frac{A}{r-\frac 12} + \frac{B}{(r-\frac 12)^2} + \frac{C}{r+\frac 12} + \frac{D}{(r+\frac 12)^2}
$$
with some constants $A, B, C, D$. These constants can be determined by multiplying with the common denominator and comparing coefficients. (There are also other method, see the above Wikipedia article.)

Here one gets
$$
 \frac{r}{(r-\frac 12)^2(r+\frac 12)^2} =  \frac{1/2}{(r-\frac 12)^2} +  \frac{-1/2}{(r+\frac 12)^2} \, .
$$

Comment: I thought that this technique is only used in integration....i completely forgot to use it here...!!!!

Comment: Partial fractions appear in many places.  But (unfortunately) some attempts to streamline calculus may omit partial fractions from that course, and then students have to learn it later in whatever course it arises... it is used in Laplace transform; it is used in complex analysis; and others.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

if $g(r)=2r+1, g(n-1)=2n-1, g(n)=? $

or if $f(r)=\dfrac1{\left(r+\dfrac12\right)^2}, f(n-1)=\dfrac1{\left(n-1+\dfrac12\right)^2}, f(n)=?$

So as $\left(r+\dfrac12\right)^2-\left(r+\dfrac12\right)^2=4\cdot r\cdot\dfrac12=?$

$$\implies\dfrac r{(2r-1)^2(2r+1)^2}=\dfrac{\left(r+\dfrac12\right)^2-\left(r+\dfrac12\right)^2}{32\left(r-\dfrac12\right)^2\cdot\left(r+\dfrac12\right)^2}=\cdots=\dfrac{f(r-1)-f(r)}{32}$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=1}^n\dfrac{f(r-1)-f(r)}{32}=\dfrac{f(0)-f(n)}{32}$$